# mongo: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query

Tags: mongodb

I have a query like:

```
.find(
    {
        "owner_id" : 1, 
        "blog_id": 1, 
        "deleted_at": { $exists: false }, 
        $text: {$search: "Some blog"}
    }, 
    {
        "score" : {$meta: "textScore"}
    }
).limit(10).skip(110).sort({"updated_at" : -1, score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
```

and search index for that query is like this

```
{
        "owner_id": 1, 
        "blog_id":1 , 
        "internal.theme": "text", 
        "internal.type": "text",
        "internal.tags": "text",
        "owner.name": "text",
        "owner.email": "text",
        "name": "text", 
        "category_id": "text",
        "tags": "text"
    },
    {
        "weights": {
            "internal.theme": 5, 
            "internal.type": 8,
            "internal.tags": 5,
            "owner.name": 9,
            "owner.email": 1,
            "name": 10, 
            "category_id": 1,
            "tags": 5
        },
        "name": "search_index",
        "background": true,
        "default_language": "english"
    }
```

but with such index query failing with memory limit on skip <= 110, so I consider to add `deleted_at` and `updated_at` to the index as those fields using by the query, so new index I made looks like this:

```
{
        "owner_id": 1, 
        "blog_id":1 , 
        "deleted_at": 1,
        "updated_at" : -1,
        "internal.theme": "text", 
        "internal.type": "text",
        "internal.tags": "text",
        "owner.name": "text",
        "owner.email": "text",
        "name": "text", 
        "category_id": "text",
        "tags": "text"
    },
    {
        "weights": {
            "internal.theme": 5, 
            "internal.type": 8,
            "internal.tags": 5,
            "owner.name": 9,
            "owner.email": 1,
            "name": 10, 
            "category_id": 1,
            "tags": 5
        },
        "name": "search_index",
        "background": true,
        "default_language": "english"
    }
```

but now query failing with the error like:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=databe.publications limit=10skip=110Tree: $and\n    blog_id $eq 1.0\n    owner_id $eq 1.0\n    $not\n        deleted_at exists\n    TEXT : query=Some blog, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: { updated_at: -1.0, score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\nProj: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\n planner returned error: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

I tried to add only one of those new fields to the index at the time, but error still the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#std-label-text-index-compound):

> If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a $text search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on the preceding keys.

Since your query does not filter on `updated_at`, it cannot precede the `text` portion of the index.